# I'm hungry. How can I reliably find meat?

Tags: starbound

I've been playing for about 2 hours now and so far I've found a grand total of 2 pieces of meat by killing monsters. One was when I had the quest to find meat, and the other was when my friend had a quest to find meat.

Do you have to kill certain types of monsters or with certain weapons for meat to drop? Does it only drop during that quest? How can I improve my odds of finding some?

Comment: Once you get a better bow and can chain kill enemies at ridiculous speeds, meat will not be a problem. I've had the higher tier bow for about two hours now and have already collected over 50 pieces of meat just by roaming the wilderness and slaughtering everything in my path. I'd estimate about 20-30% of drops are meat.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Currently meat drops at a 50% rate when using bows. [This is getting boosted to 70%](http://playstarbound.com/coming-in-tonights-update/) as well as getting a small chance to drop when using other weapons.

> Monsters now have a 70% chance to drop meat when killed with a hunting weapon, up from 50%
>
> Added hunting knife weapon that also makes monsters drop meat
>
> Monsters now have a small chance to drop meat when killed with normal weapons.

Comment: Do you know if the killing blow has to be with a bow, or ALL damage? I've had a lot of partial bow kills that suggest to me I'm getting way less than 50% drop when I hit them with the sword a few times first.

Comment: The killing blow decides what drops from the monster. Bows > Meat/leather. Swords > Pixels. And yeaa, the drop rate does seem to be much lower than 50% from what I've experienced. Though once you get the iron bow, you can kill monsters much quicker. Usually I go for the passive monsters because they don't move unless attacked and you can typically one shot them making them easy targets.

Comment: Yeah, after that patch, meat acquisition no longer appears to be a problem.

Answer (score 6):

As Katustrawfic said, killing a monster with a bow, any bow, has a chance to drop meat.  Upgrade to an iron bow if you want the process to go faster. Drop rates are being buffed.

However, there is a better way to eat.

You start with a collection of seeds from plants that only your species can eat.  You can build a stone hoe with some stone and wood.  Till the land with your hoe, and plant your seeds.

You can also pick plants out of the ground with "e", which is a very reliable way to get lots of food.

Answer (score 1):

Use the plants: both the seeds that you get from the beginning, and the other seeds you find on random planets can be used to make food.

Just build a small farm either on your home planet or on your spaceship.

This is a quick source of food, and you can regrow with the seeds you get after harvesting the plants.